# How to resume from suspend or hibernate only by the power button?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, suspend, 20.04, hibernate

My motherboard's bios/uefi don't provide an option for disabling wake up from keyboard or mouse. So I tried to disable all others devices than PWRB in /proc/acpi/wakeup, but my system ignores that and still wakes up on mouse clicks or keyboard.

- System: ubuntu 20.04
- Motherboard: H97-D3H-CF
- my   [/proc/acpi/wakeup](https://pastebin.com/55JJ8aeB)

Comment: If all else fails you instruct the system to power off (unbind) all the USB buses on suspend and power on (bind) to same address on resume. I wrote a script to do that but don't have it handy.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be even better (as integrates with systemd) :

> For a USB mouse or keyboard, you can use a udev rule to make the
> setting permanent. First, look up the PCI vendor ID of your
> mouse/keyboard using `lsusb`. For my mouse, it's `046d`:
>
> `Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver`
>
> Then create a "rules" file like my `/etc/udev/rules.d/logitech.rules`,
> only replace "046d" with the vendor ID of your own device:
>
> `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTR{power/wakeup}="disabled"`

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532839/439288

Tested. Works fine with Ubuntu 20.04 and MS Sculpt keyboard