# Automatically restore battery charging thresholds after replacing battery

Tags: 20.04, power-management, laptop, battery, battery-charging-threshold

When a laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad in my case) is used mostly plugged to the AC charger, two actions are recommended to extend battery lifespan:

1. Most effective: Simply remove the battery, and use a "laptop-as-a-desktop" PC. Prior to removing the battery I hibernate the PC, and then restore.
2. [Useful](https://news.umich.edu/tips-for-extending-the-lifetime-of-lithium-ion-batteries/): Set battery charging thresholds to something like 40%-80%, instead of the default 0%-100%.

If I set the thresholds, in my case with

```
echo 40 | sudo tee /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_start_threshold
echo 80 | sudo tee /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_stop_threshold
```

then I remove the battery as described in 1 above, and then at some later time I replace the battery, the thresholds are reset to their default values.
The threshold files are destroyed when removing the battery, as link `BAT0` is.

**Is there any way of automatically recovering the threshold files when replacing the battery?**

Comment: Move those 2 commands to a script that you execute on boot?

Comment: @Rinzwind - I am not rebooting between battery removal/replacement events.
I simply hibernate/resume.

Comment: ah then you'd expect it to be possible through a udev event  but I could not find a specific fix for this. looks like this https://askubuntu.com/a/1287497/15811 but needs specifics altered for your method.

Comment: @Rinzwind - Will check on that one. I could not find a clear path from what I searched.

Comment: Please add a tag wiki and usage excerpt for the new tag you created